# JAXB: How to implement a JAXB-compatible variant wrapper class?

Tags: java, jaxb, variant

How could I implement a "variant" class which would act as an adapter between Object and JAXB-natively-supported types?

I could then use Object in JAXB-annotated classes.

Therefor, I guess, I would need to store a type ID inside that adapter.

Any ideas?

*NOTE: With "JAXB-natively-supported types" I mean types such as:

all primitive types, `String`, `Date`, `byte[]`, `List<any-JAXB-supported-type>`.*

### Usage Scenario

```
@XmlType
class SomeClass {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(VariantAdapter.class) // WITH OR WITHOUT?
    @XmlElement
    private Object somePrimitive = null;

    // ...
}
```

### Variant Class Idea Pseudocode

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType
class Variant {
    @XmlAttribute
    private final String typeID;
    @XmlAttribute
    private final String rawXML;

    // ...
}
```

### Adapter Class (Trivial)

```
class VariantAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Variant> {
    @Override
    public Object marshal(VariantObject arg0) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public VariantObject unmarshal(Object arg0) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This existes already: See [JAXBElement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html)

Or for Collections and Map:

[utils-apl-derived project](http://www.google.com/codesearch#agM0M4Gok3c/trunk/utils-apl-derived/src/main/java/org/omnaest/utils/xml/JAXBMap.java&q=JAXBMap%20package%3ahttp://utils-apl-derived%5C.googlecode%5C.com)

Comment: Didn't work, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775345/jaxb-cant-unmarshal-jaxbelement-getting-elementnsimpl-instead